# Flexbox layout reverse by default on actual device

Tags: html, css, angular, mobile, nativescript

I am building a mobile application with angular nativescript. On some part i use flexbox layout with several elements inside it. I used an android studio emulator and everything worked fine, but when i run the application on my actual device the flexbox show he elements in reverse order and stick them to the right side of the flex as if i set `flex-direction: row-reverse`.
I am running the code at the same time on the emulator and on my device and they do not show the same result.
Maybe this is because the language on my device is right to left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore the device's right to left orientation on Android, and use the layouts without it being mirrored, you can add the following to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<manifest>
    <application
        ...
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"
        >
    </application>
</manifest>
```